# A structure with a pointer to itself inside the same structure

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

In this program i have a struct Node.There is another link pointer inside struct node.Can anyone explain how this link pointer works .What does the compiler does with this code snippet when it is run.What is the struct pointer converted to.Please explain to me what is happening at the machine level.Please excuse me if this is a stupid question.I am totally confused with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
}*top=NULL;

void main(){

}
```

This is the assembly code for this when i ran gcc -S

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .globl  top
    .bss
    .align 8
    .type   top, @object
    .size   top, 8
top:
    .zero   8
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: It works exactly the same as if it were a pointer to some other type. Why do you think any of the pointers is converted to anything somewhere?

Comment: Ok well now you've added an empty `main`, which again does nothing except exit with zero status.  And you've needlessly included some assembly code.

Comment: `link` is just a pointer that can point to a `node` object. There's absolutely nothing special about it.

Answer (score 4):

**It is not** pointer  to itself. It is a pointer to another object of the same type (it can be assigned of course with the reference to the enclosing object as well). This is used to create a linked list when one object holds the reference to another.

Comment: @sobha Further reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list - note the first diagram shows a linked listed of integers, so the data structure is what you have in your example: an integer and a pointer to the next structure